# How to move menu to the right of the logo and to clean up unused space?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I've been trying to get a layout on a website for a nonprofit my friends and I are starting but I can't figure out how to get rid of the unused spaces on the menu or how to move the menu to the right of the logo. This is what the site looks like right now without any content:
https://i.gyazo.com/96210e6a810914ef4259d0a690040324.png

I want to move get rid of the space underneath the leadership tab and to make the dark blue background only run up to a certain width on the leadership tab, as it is overlapping with my submenu. I'd also really appreciate instruction on how to move the menu to right next to the menu as opposed to below it. My source code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home </title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheethome.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
<a href="home.php"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="BEFA Inc." height="100" width="130" /></a>

</div> <!-- header !-->

<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li> <a href="WhoWeAre.php">WHO WE ARE</a>

        <ul class="wwedrop">
            <li> <a href="BefaAtAGlance.php"> BEFA AT A GLANCE</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="Leadership.php"> LEADERSHIP </a> 

                <ul class="leaders">
                    <li> <a href="BoardofDirectors.php">BOARD OF DIRECTORS </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="ExecutiveOfficers.php">EXECUTIVE OFFICERS </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="ManagementCommittee.php"> MAMANGEMENT COMMITTEE </a> </li>
                </ul> <!-- These are the links underneath/to the side of the Leadership tab of the Who We Are tab !-->
                </li>

        </ul> <!-- These are links underneath the "Who We Are" tab !-->
        </li>
    <li> <a href="Locations.php"> LOCATIONS </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="Volunteers.php"> VOLUNTEERS </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="Donate.php"> DONATE </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="FuturePlans.php"> FUTURE PLANS </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="ContactUs.php"> CONTACT US </a> </li>



</ul> <!-- These are the tabs underneath the navigation bar. Right now, only the Who We Are tab has a nested list(s) !-->

</div> <!-- navigation !-->

<div id="container">

<div id="content">

<div id="contentleft">



</div> <!-- contentleft !-->
</div><!-- content !-->
</div><!-- container !-->

<div id="sidebar">

</div>

<div id="footer">
<p> &copy;2016 Befa Inc. </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css code is:

```
img{
    border:none;
}
html{
    background: url("gradientbackground.jpg");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
body{
    color:#111517;
    font-family: Helvetica;

}
header{
    width: 50px;
    min-height: 60px; 
    margin: 0 auto;


}
#navigation{
    width: 960 px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0 px;
    right: 0 px;



}
.main-navigation a {
border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
border-top: 1px solid #888;
}

#navigation ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;

}
#navigation ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 20 px;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
#navigation ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    color:#111517;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#navigation ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #000066;
    color: #ffffff
}
#navigation ul li ul.wwedrop{
    min-width: 125 px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:999;
    left:0;
}
#navigation ul li:hover ul.wwedrop{
    display: block;
}
#navigation ul li ul.wwedrop li{
    display: block;
}
#navigation ul li ul.wwedrop li ul.leaders{
    display: none;
}

#navigation ul.wwedrop li:hover ul.leaders{
    display:block;
    margin-left:175px;
    margin-top: -70px;

}


/* the navigation list material goes here and I need to edit it so that it looks like the goldman sachs one by putting sliding feature etc. */

container{
    background:#eef7fa;
}
#footer p{
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a playing with your code in [this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqt88uet/) I've found a solution to your problems

1. The solution to the width of the "leadership" menu item is rather simple: give a `max-width` to the `#navigation ul li a:hover` so that the background will no long overlap the submenu
2. As for the problem with the menu being below the logo, simply put your logo in a `li` at the top of the `ul`.

Here's what your code will become.

**Note: The code posted here is the code I've changed, for the full code check out the JsFiddle, this is because your code is rather long to post in an answer.**

## HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <!-- <a href="home.php"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="BEFA Inc." height="100" width="130" /></a> -->
  <!-- Removed this <a> -->

</div> <!-- header !-->

<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li id="logo"><a href="home.php"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="BEFA Inc." height="100" width="130" /></a></li> 
    <!-- Added the logo here -->
    <li> <a href="WhoWeAre.php">WHO WE ARE</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#navigation ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #000066;
    max-width:130px; /* Added this to solve the overflowing background -->
    color: #ffffff
}
```

**Note: This is an example as to how you can fix it, change it in whatever way you see fit.**

[JsFiddle example again](https://jsfiddle.net/eqt88uet/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a flexbox approach for this (one solution)

see fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m4smjd1h/3/)

I placed a `word wrap` property in`#navigation ul li` so that when the window is small no overflow will be seen, the words will just wrap in their respective  div. Make the window large to see expected outcome.

Also take out the borders on the divs (it was for testing purposes)